# Are these equations true in number theory?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Are the following equations true while working in$\pmod 4$? Thank you for giving me a help.

$$3^k\equiv1,\ \text{k is even},\qquad3^k\equiv3,\ \text{k is odd}.$$

Comment: I am going to show above are true.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes: $3\equiv-1\pmod4$, so $3^k\equiv(-1)^k\pmod4$. Thus, when $k$ is even, $(-1)^k=1$, and when $k$ is odd, $(-1)^k=-1\equiv 3\pmod4$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes: since $3\equiv-1\pmod4$, we have $3^k\equiv(-1)^k\pmod4$

Answer (score 2):

Note that $3 \equiv -1 \pmod 4$. Raising both sides to the power of $k$ we have $3^k \equiv (-1)^k \pmod 4$. Choosing $k$ to be even or odd gives you the desired results (remembering that $3 \equiv -1 \pmod 4$).

Answer (score 2):

If $k$ is even, let $k=2m$

$$3^{k}=(3)^{2m}\equiv 9^{m}\equiv 1\pmod 4$$

If $k$ is odd, let $k=2m+1$

$$3^{k}=(3)^{2m+1}\equiv 9^{m}\cdot 3\equiv 3\pmod 4$$